# PCM audio data converted to MP3 and streamed has hiccups every second

Tags: angular, tcpclient, audio-streaming, naudio, networkstream

I’m trying to stream the audio using TCP client (IPEndPoint - Network Stream)

**Platforms used:**

- For UI – Angular 5
- For Streaming – webAPI

I will receive **PCM – wav data byte array** formats continuously based upon the command send.

•   When I stream the wav data byte array directly, no audio plays. (but I received the data continuously)

So I decided to convert the wav byte array to MP3 format and stream it. To convert the wav byte array to MP3 format, I have used the LameMP3FileWriter (using NAudio.Lame).

**Code:**

```
using (var outStream = new MemoryStream()) 
                {
                    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
                    {
                        using (var reader = new WaveFileReader(ms)) //wav byte array
                        {
                            using (var writer = new LameMP3FileWriter(outStream, reader.WaveFormat, 128))
                            {
                                writer.MinProgressTime = 100;
                                reader.CopyTo(writer);
                                reader.Position = 0;
                                reader.Flush();
                            }
                            outStream.Position = 0;
                            return outStream.ToArray();
                        }
                    }
                }
```

When the LampMP3FileWriter tries to read the bytes as waveFormat, it throws the error of  **“Not a WAVE file - no RIFF header”**, which means the receiving data doesn’t have the wav header. So decided to add the wav header using NAudio.

**Code:**

```
NAudio.Wave.WaveFormat waveFormat = new NAudio.Wave.WaveFormat(8000, 16, 1);
                            MemoryStream wavStream = new MemoryStream();
                            WaveFileWriter wr = new WaveFileWriter(wavStream, waveFormat);//(wavStream, waveFormat);
                            wr.Write(byteArray, 0,byteArray.Length);
                           wr.Flush();
                            wavStream.Position = 0;
```

And then converting this wav data to MP3 using the above code.

Now, the audio starts playing. But it produces some hiccups sound (gaps) for every one second. 
Please provide some solution to avoid the hiccup sound and play continuously.